# Can I use multiple LoadBalancers in Route53 Alias records?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I see an option for weighted routing in Route53 for Alias records i.e. Alias + Alias Option.

I am confused if I am supposed to create two identical A + Alias Option records or If I am supposed to enter two load balancer DNS records into the Alias Record in the AWS Console.

Basically I am trying to do weighted routing between two load balancers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either. The better choice is to use weighted resource records.

An Amazon Load Balancer has more than one IP address. DNS queries will usually return two IP addresses. If you create a single record with more than one entry, it is very likely that only the first IP address of the first load balancer will be used by clients. By using a weighted record, you will be able to balance traffic to the load balancers.

Comment: Indeed the second method works best. It is an awkward interface but after messing around a bit I was able to create two Alias records i.e `example.sample.com` pointing to separate load balancers.

Comment: @LeGardenFox Please how did you added 2 Alias records to a single name ?

Comment: @Manu, you can add a weighted routing policy to you record you're adding to your hosted zone.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted